# can somebody explain this command "php -S localhost:8000 -t public"?

Tags: php, lumen

```
/**
* Get the full server command.
*
* @return string
*/
protected function serverCommand()
{
     return sprintf('%s -S %s:%s %s/server.php',
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false)),
            $this->host(),
            $this->port(),
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument($this->laravel->basePath())
     );
}
```

didn't get this also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-S` argument starts a embedded web server from the php executable.

It is a small, not for production or public use suitable web server, primarily used for debugging or demonstrations.

The `localhost:8000` part is of course the address which the server will use.

The `-t` argument lets you specify a directory for the webroot. In this case the `public` directory will be used as the root directory for the webserver.

All in all it is a very useful debugging and testing tool since you don't have to setup a whole Apache or nginx server.

But as mentioned above: It is not suitable for production or public use since it's not a fully fletched webserver like Apache!

Comment: can we change the localhost:8000 part ?

Comment: if you mean to something like `localhost:5050` then yes, of course.

Comment: In that case you have to rewrite the host file of your system to point `test.localhost` to `localhost`. If you edited your hosts file so that `test.localhost` points to `localhost` I think you can do that but I'm not 100% sure. You would have to try that yourself.

Comment: after that should i have to write :8000

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a command for starting the server that comes built-in with PHP. The server runs at port `8000` and servers files from `./public` directory.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php